# We were unable to complete your review because we could not download your app to iTunes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, appstore-approval

i published my app to the appstore but it was rejected because of the following reason:

- We were unable to complete your review because we could not download your app to iTunes.

The review team attached the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I have no idea what that could be?
I have tested the distribution build locally (synced it via ITunes to my Iphone) and it works.

I'm also curious why there is the message " because the app signature is not valid". The app signature will already be checked automatically by the application loader and the app store ....?!

So what could i do to reproduce this on my local machine?

thankS!

Edit: I have also checked my distribution build with the command: codesign -d --vv.
It says: Authoritiy=iPhone Distribution: Our name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have a folder named "resources". For some reason the code-signing tool does not work correctly if such a folder exists, even though there is no error output or other info which would indicate this.

After I renamed my "resources" folder to something different ("ContentFiles" in my case) the problem was gone.

Most likely you cannot reproduce this on your local machine because you are working with a jailbreaked phone which does not check the signature. I would recommend not testing on a jailbreaked phone.

Answer (score 2):

> I have tested the distribution build
>   locally (synced it via ITunes to my
>   Iphone) and it works.

That is your problem then, a **real** distribution build **cannot** be tested on your device. You need to build it using your app store distribution certificate, it sounds as if you might have built it using your ad hoc distribution certificate by mistake. Check your schemes and configuration settings.

If you use XCode4 to manage the upload process for you, it will catch a lot of errors like this.

Comment: I have a jailbreaked iphone, so I guess this is why the distribution build works on the iphone.
I have build my app with the distribution certificate with monodevelop.

Comment: Monodevelop makes all the building and signing for me (i have used the correct certificates). Is there a way to upload the *.app file using XCode?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with non-Apple toolchains for this process, apologies - I missed the monotouch tag in your question.

Comment: Are there any tools to check if the app or ipa file is valid? Can i manually import the ipa or app file to the archive organizer of Xcode?

Comment: I have also checked my distribution build with the command: codesign -d --vv.
It says: Authoritiy=iPhone Distribution: Our name